# ASP pages hanging in IE6

Tags: asp-classic, internet-explorer-6

No this isn't a post from the previous century.
We are stuck with IE6 and some old ASP code using FRAMESETs

*The problem:*
An ASP page sets up a load of values in a form and then submits it to another ASP page
This second page is a FRAMESET with a map and other associated stuff, the first thing it does is read all the values to setup the layout.

All works well most of the time but sometimes it all goes horribly wrong.
The first page calls the second but the **Request.Form.Count** is **0**  and it all falls over
Once this happens it never works again until I close IE6 and restart it.
Then when I submit **Request.Form.Count** = 29 which it should be.

Any ideas as to what might be going on in IE?

For some reason calling the initial ASP page from a link on another page causes it to go wrong much more often that just pasting the URL into the address bar.
I've tried all possible methods of linking and redirecting and they all cause the problem more often than not.

Also, it works fine in every other browser I've tried but IE6 is the one we have to target.

Ken

---

Forgot to say that trying to debug with Fiddler doesn't help since it never goes wrong then

Comment: You need to show some of your ASP code if you expect someone to figure this out.

Comment: I'm trying to create a minimal version with the same problem. May be tricky though because the problem only seems to appear when it calls the map server.

Comment: One suggestion is to assign Request.Form.Count to a variable, then use the variable in the code. You should "disable friendly http error messages" in the advanced settings in IE6 as well.

Comment: Most likely local problem with the specific IE6 browser you are using to test - something there is simply corrupted thus it won't handle posting forms properly. Another option is fancy antivirus or firewall that mess with those things.

Comment: @Shadow - It certainly looks like its a local issue. I recreated the whole setup on my laptop on the train this morning and, naturally, it works perfectly (or at least it works). It was obviously all on one PC so no network, firewall involved and different anti-virus. I'm just about to try out Diodeus' suggestions, see how that goes.

Comment: Per Diodeus suggestion can't see how it can help - that value is raw and simple, such tip (assigning to local variable) can help in case of data from database (e.g. Memo field in Access lose its value once read) but not in your case. Go ahead though!

Comment: @Shadow - I wasn't hopeful but at this point I'm trying anything. Surprisingly it didn't fix it. After further messing about (or investigation as I like to think of it) it seems that the problem is in someway related to IIS. If I call the web page from a link hosted on the same server I get the error, if I call it from a link hosted on a different server I don't (?????) And we can now get the error in IE7 too.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas.. as far as I can see `Request.Form.Count` of 0 means the server did not get any posted value. It's 99% the browser fault, maybe some plugin, maybe even a malware messing with the browser internals.

Comment: @Shadow. Thanks for all the suggestions. It definitely looks like the browser is getting it's knickers in a twist. If I close it down and start with a fresh instance it's OK again, until it goes wrong then that's it. Problem with working on a corporate, locked down system is it's a pain to debug anything like this. And, as I said, when I run Fiddler it works OK. Thanks again